# וכל מאמינים - essentially the same for both כ lines

Tags: words, song-poetry, rosh-hashanah-new-year

The *piyut Vechol Maaminim* for Rosh Hashanah follows a pattern - two lines for each letter of the Hebrew alphabet, each one describing God in some way. However, the two lines for the letter *Kaf* seem to be the same thing: ([from Wikitext](https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%9C_%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D))

> הַכֹּל יָכוֹל וְכוֹלְלָם יָחַד
>
> וְכֹל מַאֲמִינִים שֶׁהוּא כֹּל יָכוֹל

Why does the *paytan* repeat himself this way? Was there nothing else for the letter כ? The second line does not seem to add anything over the first.

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=28691&st=&pgnum=7

Answer (score -2):

There seem to be a few stiches which are interrelated and reuse words but are not identical. The mem verse ("*mamlich m'lachim, vlo hamelucha*" and "*melech olam*") is another example (*bet, gimel, dalet, zayin, tet* and *pey* also reuse words and concepts). The relationship allows one idea to complement the other. As the ArtScroll machzor writes, *hakol yachol* simply means that all is within the power of Hashem whereas the addition of "*v'cholelam yachad*" means that Hashem can also do it all at the same time. I would wonder why the two lines you cite are in the opposite order -- the specific then the general claim. But that's a separate question.